# Thread safety and rospy Timer

Tags: rospy, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a little confused by how rospy.Timer works with regards to thread-safety. My understanding of callbacks in rospy in general is they're essentially handled sequentially during calls to Sleep and Spin, meaning they're implicitly threadsafe and I can modify the same data from multiple callbacks within a node without locks or other safeguards.

Timers represent a totally separate thread of execution, albeit one that still runs off of a Rate.sleep() loop. Is it safe to work with data that a Timer interacts with, or do I need to start adding locks in any nodes that have both Subscriptions and Timers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220788/thread-safety-and-rospy-timer/) by [etappan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22710/etappan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My understanding of callbacks in rospy in general is they're essentially handled sequentially during calls to Sleep and Spin, meaning they're implicitly threadsafe and I can modify the same data from multiple callbacks within a node without locks or other safeguards.

Unfortunately, no. Unlike roscpp, rospy creates a new thread for every Subscriber and Timer. In fact, `rospy.spin()` is just an [infinite loop of half-second waits](http://docs.ros.org/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-pysrc.html#spin). As such, callbacks in rospy are not threadsafe. You should use locks in any rospy node where multiple callbacks of any kind might interact.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3